# SQLAlchemy back_populates many-to-many with multiple associations (tag table)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

My question: Since Tag is connected to multiple tables via association tables, what would I put for `back_populates` on Tag. Is `back_populates` also necessary on the association tables? I'm not sure how to model `back_populates` in this scenario. See below for further details.

I have the following table structure:

[image]

Essentially, I can apply a tag to a source, or to a source key. Here are my models:

```
class Tag(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)

source_tag_assoc = Table('source_tag_assoc', Base.metadata,
    Column('source_id', Integer, ForeignKey('source.id')),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'))
)
class Source(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=source_tag_assoc, back_populates="source")

source_key_tag_assoc = Table('source_tag_assoc', Base.metadata,
    Column('source_id', Integer, ForeignKey('source_key.id')),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'))
)
class SourceKey(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=source_key_tag_assoc, back_populates="source_key")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`back_populates` must point to an actual relationship. If you don't want to define the relationship on both models, then `backref` should be used instead.

Here's how you'd adapt the models to work with `back_populates`:

```
class Tag(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    source = relationship('Source', secondary=source_tag_assoc, back_populates='tags')

class Source(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=source_tag_assoc, back_populates="source")
    source_key = relationship("SourceKey", secondary=source_key_tag_assoc, back_populates="tags")

class SourceKey(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=source_key_tag_assoc, back_populates="source_key")
```

And here's switching to `backref`, which should result in the exact same as above:

```
class Tag(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)

class Source(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=source_tag_assoc, backref="source")

class SourceKey(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=source_key_tag_assoc, backref="source_key")
```

Personally I prefer `back_populates`, because when you have over a dozen models, it's a lot easier to see all the available relationships when they are explicitly defined.

Comment: Note - backref is considered legacy : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html